# String Number format with "/" for thousand separator

Tags: string, vba, string-formatting, number-formatting, separator

The `sValA` variable.

For example `sValA = 23224560`.

I need below format:

> **23/224/560**

(Assigning the `/` character as **thousand separator**.)

*What I was tried:*

The `Format(23224560, "#,##0")` returns: **23,224,560**

But `Format(23224560, "#/##0")` returns: **23224/560** ! ***(Needed)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a thousand separator other than *the Number Format recognized by your system* - your thousand separator appears to be a comma. To use anything other than the system's thousand separator, you can achieve the result you want by repeating the pattern:

```
?Format(23224560, "###/###/##0")
23/224/560
```

Of course, that only works if your number is at least 7 digits, and at most 9 digits. You could use a `Select` block to do the formatting:

```
Dim sValA As String
sValA = 23224560

Dim result As String

Select Case Len(sValA)
  Case 1 To 3
      result = Format$(sValA, "##0")
  Case 4 To 6
      result = Format$(sValA, "###/##0")
  Case 7 To 9
      result = Format$(sValA, "###/###/##0")
  'Case...
End Select
```

PS - You'd be better off with the `Format$` function which returns a `String`, as opposed to `Format` which returns a `Variant (String)`.

Comment: When I performing `UpdateBookmark StrBkMk:="Temp_GrandTotal", StrTxt:=StringNumberFormating(CStr(sValA))`, It will returns: **000/140/10**. How can correct above to the formatted number been: **10/140/000** when preforming Type in the MS-Word?

Comment: What's the value of `sValA` and how do you want it displayed in Word?

Comment: The value is **10140000** and I want displays: **10/140/000** in the Word.

Comment: I don't know what your UpdateBookmark routine does, but this statement works just fine: `sValA = 10140000
: ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Temp_GrandTotal").Range.Text = StringNumberFormating(CStr(sValA))`

Comment: The problem is my Word Document has `Right to Left` direction.

Comment: Is it possible performing above for the `Right to Left` situations in MS-Word Document?

Comment: You might want to ask a question about inserting `10/140/000` as text in a right-to-left document, and tag as [tag:word], [tag:vba] and [tag:right-to-left]